# Safely call openSSL functions from inside a shared library

Tags: c, openssl, linker, shared-libraries

I have implemented a client program that uses openSSL to connect to the server in the secure way. The client is compiled as a shared object (SO), such that third party applications can load it and connect to the server. (Note: The SO is compiled in a way such that openSSL is statically linked to it. [If knowing this has an effect on your answer])

It works fine in many applications. However, if the third party application itself loads openSSL for any other reason, a segmentation fault occurs when the library tries to invoke `SSL_library_init()`. It seems that, calling the non-reentrant function `SSL_library_init()` twice, leads to the segmentation fault. The first call occurs in the main program and the second invocation triggers by my shared object.

Is there any method to solve this problem? For example, by separating the main and SO calls of `SSL_library_init()` and enforcing SO to call the function in a separate memory space? Or, by renaming symbol names of openSSL using something like `objcopy --prefix-symbols=...` command?

In summary, is it possible to safely call the non-reentrant function `SSL_library_init` from inside a shared library when I do not know what programs will load this library?

Obviously, I do not have control over third party applications. So, I cannot determine where and how it should call the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-response:

set `-fvisibility=hidden` to hide internal symbols of openSSL from outer modules in the compilation process of openSSL.

OR

use `-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL` when you compile the SO. For example: `g++ -shared -o mylib.so obj1.o obj2.o -L/path/to/openssl/static-libs -lssl -lcrypto -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL`

I prefer the second method because it also solved the problem of version conflicts on openssl engine (at least in my case).

Answer (score 2):

> However, if the third party application itself loads openSSL for any
> other reason, a segmentation fault occurs when the library tries to
> invoke `SSL_library_init()`.

This doesn't sound like a reentrancy issue, because I don't see how a client application could cause `SSL_library_init()` to be reentered.  I am therefore inclined to think that the docs use the wrong term.  I suspect that what they mean is that `SSL_library_init()` is not thread safe, or perhaps simply that it must not be called multiple times.

> It works fine in many applications. However, if the third party
> application itself loads openSSL for any other reason, a segmentation
> fault occurs when the library tries to invoke SSL_library_init(). It
> seems that, calling the non-reentrant function SSL_library_init()
> twice, leads to the segmentation fault. The first call occurs in the
> main program and the second invocation triggers by my shared object.

This probably reflects a limitation of your design, related to bundling standard OpenSSL into your shared library.  Doing so creates a substantial risk that applications will dynamically link two copies of OpenSSL, one in the form of its standard shared libraries, and one as included in your shared library.  Although that would not automatically mean the resulting program would break, it does open up multiple avenues for breakage.

In particular, having multiple copies of OpenSSL linked into the application could result in some of the functions of one copy calling functions or accessing external objects belonging to the other copy.  You might nevertheless get away with that, but there are multiple ways for it to go wrong even in the case where the two copies of OpenSSL are exactly the same version, built with identical options.  The possibilities expand as the versions or build options of the two copies diverge.

> Is there any method to solve this problem? For example, by separating
> the main and SO calls of SSL_library_init() and enforcing SO to call
> the function in a separate memory space?

The main way I can think of to provide for a "separate memory space" is to launch a child process.  Indeed, I could see providing a thin wrapper program around your SO to serve this purpose, and it is conceivable that it would be useful more generally.  But note that this is not a solution to the problem as posed, but rather a workaround.  And that may be perfectly fine.

> Or, by renaming symbol names
> of openSSL using something like objcopy --prefix-symbols=... command?

Modifying all external symbols exposed by your bundled copy of OpenSSL sounds like a promising option, but I would do it at (OpenSSL) build time, not by trying to modify the SO after it's built.

> In summary, is it possible to safely call the non-reentrant function
> SSL_library_init from inside a shared library when I do not know what
> programs will load this library?

Again, I don't think reentrancy is the issue.  Thread safety might be an issue, or there might be an issue revolving around dynamic linking details.  Either one of those would likely be resolved by better isolating your bundled copy of OpenSSL from the client application, **and** the client application from your bundled OpenSSL.  The best way I can think of to accomplish both sides of that when you are in control only of one component is to change symbol names to avoid collisions.

Comment: So, it seems that the main problem is "having multiple copies of OpenSSL linked into the application" that "could result in some of the functions of one copy calling functions or accessing external objects belonging to the other copy", as mentioned in the response. Thanks for the precise explanation. According to this response, I corrected the title and changed it from "Safely call non-reentrant function such as `SSL_library_init` from inside a shared library" to "safely call openSSL functions from inside a shared library".